# ¿como puedo realizar una división con datos que registro desde un EditText y mostrarlos en otro activty en un ListView

Tags: android

desde un activity registro los datos de Kilometros, litros de gasolina, costo por litro, costo total y fecha que se guardan en una base de datos. Pero quiero que en otro activity me muestre el resultado de la division de kilometros/litros

```
public class RegistrarDatos extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText kilometraje,litrosGasolina,costoL, costoT, fecha;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrar_datos);

        kilometraje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_kilometraje);
        litrosGasolina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Gasolina);
        costoL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CostoL);
        costoT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CostoT);
        fecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Fecha);
    }



public void onClick(View view){

       if(ComprobarCampos()){
           Intent intent = new Intent(this,Rendimiento.class);

           String dato1 = kilometraje.getText().toString();
           String dato2 = litrosGasolina.getText().toString();
           int num1 = Integer.parseInt(dato1);
           int num2 = Integer.parseInt(dato2);
           int div = num1/num2;
           String resultado = String.valueOf(div);
           intent.putExtra("DIV",resultado);
            registrarDatos();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hay campos vacios",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void registrarDatos() {
        ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_ControlGasolina",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_KILOMETRAJE,kilometraje.getText().toString());
        values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_GASOLINA,litrosGasolina.getText().toString());
        values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_COSTOL,costoL.getText().toString());
        values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_COSTOT,costoT.getText().toString());
        values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_FECHA,fecha.getText().toString());
        try{
            Long idResultado = db.insertOrThrow(utilidades.TABLA_REGISTROS,null,values);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ID registro: "+idResultado,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.print("ERROR----------------->"+e);
        }


        db.close();
        limpiar();

    }

    public boolean ComprobarCampos(){
        if(kilometraje.getText().toString().isEmpty() || litrosGasolina.getText().toString().isEmpty() || costoL.getText().toString().isEmpty() || costoT.getText().toString().isEmpty() || fecha.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void limpiar() {
        kilometraje.setText("");
        litrosGasolina.setText("");
        costoL.setText("");
        costoT.setText("");
        fecha.setText("");


    }
}
```

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PRIMERA ACTIVIDAD**

```
    public class RegistrarDatos extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText kilometraje,litrosGasolina,costoL, costoT, fecha;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrar_datos);

            kilometraje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_kilometraje);
            litrosGasolina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Gasolina);
            costoL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CostoL);
            costoT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CostoT);
            fecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Fecha);
        }



        public void onClick(View view){

           if(ComprobarCampos()){
               Intent intent = new Intent(this,Rendimiento.class);

               String dato1 = kilometraje.getText().toString();
               String dato2 = litrosGasolina.getText().toString();
               int num1 = Integer.parseInt(dato1);
               int num2 = Integer.parseInt(dato2);
               int div = num1/num2;
               String resultado = String.valueOf(div);
               intent.putExtra("DIV",resultado);
               registrarDatos();

               //Te faltaba iniciar la actividad
               startActivity(intent);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hay campos vacios",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        private void registrarDatos() {
            ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_ControlGasolina",null,1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_KILOMETRAJE,kilometraje.getText().toString());
            values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_GASOLINA,litrosGasolina.getText().toString());
            values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_COSTOL,costoL.getText().toString());
            values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_COSTOT,costoT.getText().toString());
            values.put(utilidades.CAMPO_FECHA,fecha.getText().toString());
            try{
                Long idResultado = db.insertOrThrow(utilidades.TABLA_REGISTROS,null,values);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ID registro: "+idResultado,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (SQLException e){
                System.out.print("ERROR----------------->"+e);
            }


            db.close();
            limpiar();
        }

        public boolean ComprobarCampos(){
            if(kilometraje.getText().toString().isEmpty() || litrosGasolina.getText().toString().isEmpty() || costoL.getText().toString().isEmpty() || costoT.getText().toString().isEmpty() || fecha.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void limpiar() {
            kilometraje.setText("");
            litrosGasolina.setText("");
            costoL.setText("");
            costoT.setText("");
            fecha.setText("");
        }
  }
```

**SEGUNDA ACTIVIDAD**

```
public class SegundaActividad extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otra_actividad);

        //Capturas el intent
        Intent intent = get Intent();

        String resultado = "";

        if(intent != null){

            resultado = intent.getStringExtra("DIV");
        }

        TextView tuTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tu_textview_id);
        tuTextView.setText(resultado);
    }
}
```